# Secure a php proxy?

Tags: php, hash, proxy, md5

So on my site (https://example.com) I have a page that parses the last.fm API and pulls back the images off their akamai CDN and displays them on the page.

The thing is all the images are served on HTTP ONLY, https is not supported.

e.g: http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/76030502.png

I have an image proxy written in php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
if(isset($_GET['img'])){echo file_get_contents($_GET['img']);}
?>
```

This works perfectly, however, is NOT secure at all, I want it so that only my server can use the image proxy and as such a hash in the URL might be the best option?

`https://example.com/proxy.php?url=http://last.fm/image.jpg&hash=hashhere`

I had thought of using:

```
md5($_GET['img']."privatekeyhere");
```

Then my problem turned to, how to I put the private key in the javascript code without the whole world having access to it?

Any help much appreciated.

---

I have since written this script that is somewhat effective but still open to being circumvented:

```
<?php
$args = $_GET['q'];
$date = date('m-d-Y-h-i', time());

list($hash,$img,$auth) = explode("/", $args);

if($hash=="need" && $auth=="key"){
    $checksum = md5($img.$date);
    echo $checksum;
}

if($hash==md5($img.$date))
{
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    echo file_get_contents('http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/' . $img);
}
?>
```

This can be called like so: `https://www.mylesgray.com/lastfm/need/76030502.png/key`

The auth code can then be plugged in to display the image: `https://www.mylesgray.com/lastfm/{code-here}/76030502.png`

However it doesn't take long for someone to figure out they can set up a script to poll for a key every minute - any advice?

Comment: "how to I put the private key in the javascript code": why do you need to?, keep it server-side, and if you have an authentication step for users, you should give them an accessToken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate unique tokens. You're on the right track with a hash, but if you keep your private key constant, it'll eventually get brute-forced. From there, rainbow tables say hi.

You're effectively going to have to borrow a leaf or two from mechanisms used to prevent CSRF abuse, as you're effectively trying to do the same thing: limit the user to one query per token, with a token that cannot be regenerated by them.

There are tons of ways to do this, and the usual trade-off is between efficiency and security. The simplest is what you've suggested - which is easily brute-forceable.
At the opposite end of the spectrum is the DB approach - generate a unique token per visit, store it in a DB, and validate subsequent calls against this. It is pretty DB-intensive but works out relatively well - and is virtually impossible to break unless the token generation is weak.

Comment: But the proxy should not allow external sources, in that it is only there to fix and "content insecure" warnings on my site. So what will giving that user a unique token do? - Sorry I have never had to do something like this before.

Comment: Assuming you've put secure tokens in place, all you now need to do is to give your server the ability to generate tokens. Voila, job done, only your server now knows how to go through the authentication system (as that is exactly what you've just built).

Comment: But the above url will be called from a javascript source - thus browser-side, it will need to pass the hash to the url in order to auth, what i'm trying to understand is how the javascript will work out the matching auth code?

Comment: Okay. In this case, you'll need to write a token generator that the JS script will call to get a token. Don't write the algorithm in JS, it'll only get abused. Get the client to send a request to a given script, where you give them back a token with a limited validation time (say 5 minutes). Throttle requests per IP address so they cannot just ping the script every 5 minutes if necessary.

Comment: Prefect just the answer I was after, thanks man. One last thing - as JS is public facing - when the JS calls for a token then the url where that token is generated is then public - meaning anyone can program for it and regain an auth code every 5 mins? Perhaps restricting requests to my domain would combat this?

Comment: I have added a code example above of what I have implemented, it seems secure enough as it only allows the key to be active for 1 minute then it stops working?

Comment: Your current version is pretty decent. It'll require people to query your server for a token for each individual image every minute, which will weed out most "bad" people. In the end, there is no way other than throttling to prevent people from requesting multiple tokens over and over (a good throttle method is to build a currency-like system, by the way. Each page call, they get, say, 2 "coins". A proxy token costs 10. So, they have to do 5 page loads on your site to be entitled for 1 minute of play time on the proxy).