# Limit the number of a client requests sent to a server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, api, nusoap

I have an `API` with `PHP` and `nusoap` and it is launched on a server with `Apache` web server. Different remote clients send requests to my API functions and get response. I want to restrict clients requests to a specific function in this way:

There is a limitation for requests which can be sent by a client in every second and this limitation is stored in `mysql` database. Each client must be able to send requests up to its limitation. For example if the maximum requests defined for a client is 300, it is not allowed to send more than 300 requests in second.

How can I implement this rule with PHP or Apache?

Comment: You can not stop the clients from doing anything - if they want to send requests, they will send requests. What you can do, is decide how you want to handle those requests, once they have reached your server. (Just mentioning this because it is an important distinction, and they way your question is phrased it seems doubtful if you are aware of that.)

Comment: you may want to take a look at [stackoverflow: secure-a-php-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440663/secure-a-php-proxy)

Answer (score 1):

the perfect solution is to handle that with PHP. Every request which hits you API should have an unique token. It can be added to the URL address like `http://yousite/api/method?token=sample_token` . This token is assigned to specific client / user.

You just need to log this action into database. The table will have pretty simple structure - `id, client_id(token), created_at, action`. Action is not mandatory, but might be useful in the future.

Now, you can add a handler to your API which will limit a number of requests . You can add this at the beginning of every action in controller, in event listener before controller is created or in security layer.

```
if (new (ApiRequestsRepository())->getNumberOfRequestsForLastHour($token) > 300) {
     throw new Exception('Number of allowed requests exceeded. 300 requests per hour allowed.');
}
```

I hope that's helpful. I may give you more specific example if you say what kind of framework do you use.

The `ApiRequestsRepository` is a class which will provide youa number of already used tokens by `getNumberOfRequestsForLastHour` method. 
The method `getNumberOfRequestsForLastHour` will call a query more or less like this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM actions 
   JOIN client ON (client.id = actions.client_id)
   WHERE client.token = $token 
     AND WHERE created_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW() GROUP BY token;
```

Comment: @pioter Pasich I have not used a framework and I have developed it by PHP without using a framework. Of course I will use a framework in the future. Can I use your solution  without using a framework?

Comment: Yes. of course. I have updated my post to help you more. If that solves your problem or helps pleas mark this answer as helpful